# Do aliens exist as per hindu sacred texts?

Tags: scripture, vedas, vedic-gods

I've heard that there are Quantum Multiverse.
I wanted to know in other universe is there any mention that someone (aliens) exist on another planet

Comment: What do you mean by aliens? There are other lokas with entire different species living there.

Comment: @wikash_ my question is that, like our planet, Do any other similar planets exist ?(any mention in texts) how many. Do Parallel Universes exist

Comment: Yes and yes. There are according to the scriptures parallel universes and other lokas in which different species live.

Comment: While I cannot confirm the existence of the parallel universe as we need more proof to back it. I can tell you that there are different lokas as in similar planets like earth or even different where other beings currently exist. Also the term "aliens" may not be the appropriate to describe them. I prefer to use "celestial beings" and prefer them refer to us the same way, cheers.

Comment: @VikramPalakurthi That nomenclature is just unnecessarily confusing for humans born on other planets and "celestial beings" born on Earth.

Comment: I will tell Parijatha flower, kusha grass and onion juice taste are all alien

Comment: Because Krishna fought with indra to bring it from swarthy lokha kusha grass  came out kurma avatra  and onion rasha is indeed essence amritga

Comment: @PrasannaR I think he means beings not plants or any of the sort.

Comment: Please clarify about the word alien. Does it mean any living being?